# Kotlin Room Coroutines Codelab Question (beginner)

Tags: android, kotlin

Good day, I'm working through the coroutines with room codelab and I have some doubt as to when it's okay to simply call a databaseDao from a ViewModel and when you need to put it inside a suspend fun and launch it from a Coroutine with Dispatchers(IO).

In particular, in the code, which can be found [here](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/tree/master/TrackMySleepQualityCoroutines), inside SleepTrackerViewModel on line 37 they declare a val directly in the class like this:

`private val nights = database.getAllNights()`

Where the `database` is the dao and getAllNights is a query and it's called without any Coroutine or suspend fun. Shouldn't this be done from a coroutineScope within a suspend fun?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

As seen in the [`SleepDatabaseDao`](https://github.com/google-developer-training/android-kotlin-fundamentals-apps/blob/master/TrackMySleepQualityCoroutines/app/src/main/java/com/example/android/trackmysleepquality/database/SleepDatabaseDao.kt), `getAllNights()` is defined as:

```
fun getAllNights(): LiveData<List<SleepNight>>
```

Getting a `LiveData` does not need to be called on a background thread or from within a coroutine scope.

Comment: Thank you so much! I thought it could have something to do with it returning LiveData but wasn't sure that was it.